# Posting to asp.net API

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to add an API into in existing web forms site. A) sorry everything was written in VB, B) I'm somewhat new to API's so really don't know what I'm doing.

I'm basing my example on the the tutorial from microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms

I have created a default controller (called vSend.vb) in a Controllers folder and added a route in global.asax

```
Namespace Controllers
Public Class vSend
    Inherits ApiController

    ' GET: api/vSend
    Public Function GetValues() As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Return New String() {"value1", "value2"}
    End Function

    ' GET: api/vSend/5
    Public Function GetValue(ByVal id As Integer) As String
        Return "value"
    End Function

    ' POST: api/vSend
    Public Sub PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As String)

    End Sub

    ' PUT: api/vSend/5
    Public Sub PutValue(ByVal id As Integer, <FromBody()> ByVal value As String)

    End Sub

    ' DELETE: api/vSend/5
    Public Sub DeleteValue(ByVal id As Integer)

    End Sub
End Class  End Namespace


 Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:="DefaultApi", routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}", defaults:=New With {Key .id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.[Optional]})
End Sub
```

I'm using PostMan to try to post a simple JSON packet and get the response: "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:91/api/vSend'.",
"MessageDetail": "No route providing a controller name was found to match request URI 'http://localhost:91/api/vSend'"

[Image from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4peBK.png)

Any help to get me pointed in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For any web method (api), then you have to set/tell/tag/setup the code as being a web method.

So, assuming you have jQuery installed (don't we all?).

So, on the given web page? (in place of creating a seperate asmx page?).

Then in code behind you need:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
```

Then, for any method in that page, you have to tag the method as "webmethod".

And since there is NOT a page-post back, then this means that web method will have to be a "static" method in the code behind.

So, let's create a web method that accepts firstname and a lastname, and returns a full name.

So, code behind is now this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub


<WebMethod>
Public Shared Function MyFullName(strFirstName As String, strLastName As String) As String

    Dim sResult As String =
        strFirstName & " " & strLastName

    Return sResult


End Function
```

Now, on the client side (markup) we have this:

```
<div style="padding:35px">

    <div style="float:left">
        Enter First Name:
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        </asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;margin-left:15px">
        Enter First Name:
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        </asp:TextBox>
    </div>


    <div style="float:left;margin-left:15px">
        Result:
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstLast" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        </asp:TextBox>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="ajax (web method call)"                
        OnClientClick="testwebcall();return false"                
    />

    </div>

<script>

    function testwebcall() {
        var tFirstName = $('#txtFirst').val()
        var tLastName = $('#txtLast').val()
        var tFirstLast = $('#txtFirstLast')

        var URL = "TestAjaxCall.aspx/MyFullName" 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: URL,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({strFirstName : tFirstName, strLastName : tLastName}),
            success: function (mydata) {
                // ok, have return value, place in 
                tFirstLast.val(mydata.d)
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

So, now when we run, we get/see this:

[image]